# What is the difference between these two event in angular2

Tags: angular

What is the difference between these two event in angular2:

```
<rb-recipes-list (recipeSelected)="selectedRecipe = $event"></rb-recipes-list>
```

and

```
<rb-recipe-item [recipe]="recipe" (click)="onSelected(recipe)"></rb-recipe-item>
```

And why can't they be written the same way. How are they related.

The following are written in the same component:

```
@Output() recipeSelected = new EventEmitter<Recipe>();

    onSelected(recipe: Recipe) {
        this.recipeSelected.emit(recipe);
        console.log(recipe);
      }
```

Am new to angular2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<rb-recipes-list (recipeSelected)="selectedRecipe = $event"></rb-recipes-list>
```

here `(recipSelected)` is a **custom event** (not a built-in javascript event). Generally Whenever you want to fire any event and `send data` from **child to parent** OR whenever you want to `fire a custom event` and `execute any function` in **parent component** So you need to declare it within `rb-recipes-list component` with **EventEmitter** and **Output** APIs as shown below,

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Output} from '@angular/core';
@Component({..})
export class RbRecipesListComponent{
  @Output rbRecipesList = new EventEmitter();          //<<<=== way to declare custom event

     // Then you can fire this anywhere like this,
     // 1st way

   somefun(){
     this.rbRecipesList.emit('Angular2')     

     //rbRecipesList now emits value(Angular2) which will be received 
     //by $event defined in parentController eg. (recipeSelected)="selectedRecipe = $event"
     // So Angular2 will be assinged to selectedRecipe variable.

   }

}
```

**OR**

**parentController**

```
<rb-recipes-list (recipeSelected)="onSelected($event)"></rb-recipes-list>  
                                                      //<<<==changed line

export class parentController(){
   onSelected(value){
      this.selectedRecipe=value;                      //<<<===Angular2 will be assigned to selectedRecipe 
   }
}

import {Component, EventEmitter, Output} from '@angular/core';
    @Component({..})
    export class RbRecipesListComponent{
      @Output rbRecipesList = new EventEmitter();     //<<<=== way to declare custom event

         // Then you can fire this anywhere like this,
         // 2st way

       somefun(){
         this.rbRecipesList.emit('Angular2')     

         //rbRecipesList now emits value(Angular2) which will be received by $event
         // This time onSelected() function will be fired at a same time
         // So Angular2 will be assinged to selectedRecipe variable.

       }

    }
```

---

```
<rb-recipe-item [recipe]="recipe" (click)="onSelected(recipe)"></rb-recipe-item>
```

This is normal **javascript (Angular2 defined) click event**. So once `rb-recipe-item` is **clicked**,  `onSelected()` will be fired in parent controller.

```
export class parentController(){
       onSelected(){}
}
```

Comment: thanks once again. Yes your explanation is quite clear, though I'd have to go through it more than once.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! Yes its a quite long but worth to read for better understanding.